# My Jstree dont show any folder

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, jstree

I'm trying to create a jstree that is connected to my Dropbox API. I want to show all my folders in my Dropbox to jstree but there's no output and there's no error to it just said that:

> XHR finished loading: POST "https://api.dropboxapi.com/1/delta".

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Ajax JS Tree</title>
    <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jstree/3.3.3/themes/default/style.min.css" />
    <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jstree/3.3.3/jstree.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="container"></div>
    <script>
        $(function() {
            var fullTree;
            var url = 'https://api.dropboxapi.com/2/files/alpha/get_metadata';
            var access_token = 'I-pZSjTC4tAAAAAAAAAAl1Wpza91KvV_17XKarAsyEMpC78Ereo9-uO2QVE-Sx0a';
            $.ajax({
                url: url,
                data: fullTree,
                method: "POST",
                dataType: "json",
                beforeSend: function(request) {
                    request.setRequestHeader("Authorization", 'Bearer ' + access_token);
                },

                success: function(fullTree) {
                    $('#container').jstree({
                        'core': {
                            "data": fullTree,

                            "check_callback": true,

                        },
                        "plugins": ["themes", "contextmenu", "ui"]
                    });

                },

                error: function(xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
                    alert(xhr.status);
                    alert(thrownError);
                }
            });

        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

I tried everything including AJAX and jQuery on it but nothing happens.

Comment: doesn't look like you are using the json from the success callback

Answer (score 0):

It seems you put your url variable as data. I think this is a mistake. Isn't it the retrieved json variable you want as data ?

```
"json_data" : {
            "data" :json,
             'data' : function (node) {
                return { 'id' : node.id };
            }
```

Comment: I tried to put the 'json' variable a while ago and nothing happens its always showing XHR finished loading: POST "https://api.dropboxapi.com/1/delta".

Comment: Try an output of json.data (console.log(json.data)), what does it say

Comment: Its Undefined sir. there must ne something wrong in my ajax call? or in my jstree call?

Comment: And console.log(json) ? also undefined?

Comment: Yes sir. Its also undefined Im trying to edit my codes I think there some logical error

Comment: Yes, there must be something wrong with the ajax call, otherwise json would not been undefined. Never worked with dropbox api so can't help you further, sir. Good luck though :)